# Mini Voice Recorder for Arduino

Tags: sensors, arduino-micro, audio, sound

I am trying to find a small voice recorder that I can use with my Arduino Micro, and I found [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10653). It is exactly what I am looking for, but it is now a retired product. I googled `ISD1932`, but many other sites are out of stock or not selling it anymore. Is there something of this size that does the same things, and why is it retired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISD 1820 voice recorder module for arduino. Or ISD series or ISD 1700 series voice recorder module. Which I think you can still buy these. Will work  with 8bit CPU. Or can be interfaced to 8 bit CPU. You could use multiple modules to increase recording times. I can give you more of an answer if you tell me more about your problem. ISD4004 IC can record for 8 minutes.

Comment: This was perfect!

Answer (score 2):

FYI, these ISD chips sample audio and store a variable charge on a single flash like cell. They do not convert a sample to a numerical value. There is no data to be read from the chips nor (AFAIK) is there an opportunity to write data to play back to the chips. AFAIK, for us common people, each ISD chip needs to have its recording entered individually. Think of it like duplicating cassette tapes. Think about this when considering how to go about building your project.

Comment: I  think the OP was asking can he get a chip on a breakout board -or something that can be interfaced to an 8 bit arduino-rather  than an IC chip.

Comment: Yes, agreed.  I debated on answering or commenting.  But this is the Arduino bit of stackexchange and I thought the information useful not just for the OP but for others exploring using the same chip.

Answer (score 1):

It's retired because there is no market for it any more. Modern microcontrollers are more than powerful enough to handle simple audio without the need for external chips like that.

Some can even do full blown multi-channel HD audio with just the addition of a CODEC chip (that's a fancy name for a DAC to you and me).

Even a lowly 8-bit Arduino can play audio directly (though at low quality) through PWM from an SD card.

Comment: @Manjenko Thank you. That helped me understand why it is retired. But is there a substitution for it that would work with [this](http://bit.ly/28WOzGw)?

Comment: Yes, it's called don't use that, use something better. Maybe a Teensy 3.1 or something like that...?

Comment: Please don't be rude. Also, I already bought that because I thought people on StackExchange could help me.

Comment: I'm not being rude. I'm being serious. 8 bitters have a role, but that role is not working with audio. Teensy's are very similar in design and price but have much more power and are more suited to audio work.

Comment: [Dat Han Bag's answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/30885/27962) worked.